# Getting keyboard events saved into an array with graphic window on

Tags: c, allegro5

My little project has a window popping up, greeting the user and asking for their name. And that's where it is to get the keys pressed and have those saved into an array to be able to use later.
Except, when I run this part of code that is supposed to do so:

```
while (done != 0)
{
    GFX_GetKeyPress(&key);
    if (key == ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE)
    {
        done = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        key = GFX_GetKeyPress(*(user.name+1));
    }
}
```

With the array being hidden in a structure:

```
struct user_details
{
   char name[40];
}
```

and called in the main function by `struct user_details user`.
Also, the `GFX_GetKeyPress(int * keypress_ptr)` is a function from a library we've got at the university, and is used for us to know which key is pressed.

Except, when I use run the code, that part gets completely ignored. The program only informs the user it wants their name, which is before that part, and then continues to asking other things, which is after that.
I'm mostly sure I've followed the instructions we got during our classes, but somehow I must not be and I have no idea what I've messed up. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am seeing your code properly, when you say `key = GFX_GetKeyPress(*(user.name+1));`, you are actually dereferencing the second character in the CString `name[40]` array, so what you are doing would be basically equivalent to calling `key = GFX_GetKeyPress('A');`. I am quite surprised you haven't received a compiler warning for this. First of all, you're passing the wrong type (int vs. char). However, more importantly, you are passing a character value where a pointer to an integer is expected. Along with being surprised you aren't getting a warning, I'm thoroughly shocked that your program didn't segfault because of trying to access invalid memory.

If `GFX_GetKeyPress(int * keypress_ptr)` is capable of handling a cstring buffer instead of an integer pointer and assuming you intend to pass the pointer to the second character in the user.name buffer, then all you should need to do is: `key = GFX_GetKeyPress(user.name+1)` (which will pass the address of the first element of the name array + 1 byte for the next index.)

I have not worked with Allegro, so I'm not sure about all of the ins-and-outs of the library, but that's just standard C pointer knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To add to SpencerD's answer, you're only storing one key, as well as passing incompatible types and ignoring every other keypress.

Assuming GFX_GetKeyPress returns the next character in the key buffer, something like this would be more appropriate :

```
int index = 0;
while (GFX_GetKeyPress(&key) != ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE) {
   if (index < 40) {/// Hardcoded constants are bad
      user.name[index] = key;
      ++index;
   }
   else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Although modal loops are generally ill advised, this should work.